# Laravel Mix Notification on Docker - NO NOTIFICATION DISPLAY

Tags: docker, laravel-5, docker-compose, laravel-mix, laradock

I'm having a Laravel Project and I run it using Laradock. Also I added vue js components on it and run `npm run dev` or `npm run watch` to compile every changes I made but now it didn't display any Laravel Mix Notification whenever I try to compile.

Before I use xampp and the notification works fine. I just happened to know that using Docker in my project is great.

If anyone knows how to make my Laravel Mix Notification work again in Docker. Thanks!

Comment: Are you running npm inside a container?

Comment: yes I am @NikoPeltoniemi

Comment: Docker can't send the notifications to your host machine. If you need the notifications you'll need to run npm on the host machine.